# Facebook Sdk Login , Infinite Looping in Android ,How to fix it?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Implement facebook login with permission, that time performed infinite looping why, i can't understant. I implement according to given step on facebook devloper side, my code is given under.

```
mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbLoginButton);
fbLoginButton.setPublishPermissions(PrefrennceList.FB_PUBLISH_PERMISSION);

fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            Utility.storeString(mPreferences, PrefrennceList.FB_ACCESSTOKEN, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Utility.storeString(mPreferences, PrefrennceList.FB_USER_ID, loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());

            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SocialLoginActivity.this, PrefrennceList.FB_READ_PERMISSION);

            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added `logInWithReadPermissions()` method inside `onSuccess()` callback. Remove that and add that before as below

```
mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbLoginButton);
fbLoginButton.setPublishPermissions(PrefrennceList.FB_PUBLISH_PERMISSION);

LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SocialLoginActivity.this, PrefrennceList.FB_READ_PERMISSION);

fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

        Utility.storeString(mPreferences, PrefrennceList.FB_ACCESSTOKEN, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
        Utility.storeString(mPreferences, PrefrennceList.FB_USER_ID, loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId())
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
});


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 }
```